# Creating a C program with recursive function to check if a given integer is a multiple of 4. Why is my implementation failing?

Tags: c, recursion, command-line-arguments, function-definition

I was trying to create this program:

> function power4 takes a command line argument "n", it converts it into an integer (because in the command line everything is formatted as a string), and it does something to say whether or not "n" is multiple of 4.

> output format must be the same way: "4*i=n", and it's required to use recursion.

because I need to use recursion, I cannot use modulus "%" operand; i've used subtractions, and the base case of recursion must be when "n == 0", or when "n < 0" (or when n = 1, if it's not multiple of 4), inductive step is "power4(n - 4, i + 1)".

I've used strtol function to convert "n" to an integer, and I've used *p to check if strtol was successful or not.

I did it in the following way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void power4(int n, int i) {
    if (n < 0 || n == 1) {
        printf("!p4"); 
        return; 
    } 
    if (n == 0) {
        printf("4*");
        printf("%d", i);
        printf("=%d", n); 
    }
    power4(n - 4, i + 1); 

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        return 1; 
    }
    int ptr = 0; 
    int* p = &ptr; 
    int c = strtol(argv[1], p, 10); 
    if (p == NULL) {
        return 1; 
    }
    power4(c, 1); 
    return 0; 
}
```

I've tried this program with "n = 12" (i.e a multiple of 4) but it says it's not multiple, why is it not working properly?

EDIT: this is the updated version of my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void power4(int n, int i) {
    if (n < 0 || n == 1) {
        printf("!p4"); 
        return; 
    } 
    if (n == 0) {
        printf("4*");
        printf("%d", i);
        printf("=%d", n); 
        return; 
    }
    power4(n - 4, i + 1); 
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        return 1; 
    }
    int c = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10); 
    power4(c, 1); 
    return 0; 
}
```

EDIT: I've changed the recursive algorithm, but now the error is that argc!=2 is always true, and therefore it returns always 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void power4(int n1, int i, int n2) {
    // base case
    if (n1 % 4 != 0 && n1 != 1) {
        printf("!p4"); 
        return; 
}
    if (n1 == 1) {
        printf("4^%d=%d", i, n2); 
        return; 
    }
    // inductive step
    power4(n1 / 4, i + 1, n2); 
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        return 1; 
    }
    int c = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10); 
    power4(c, 0, c); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Why not just divide the number by 4 and compare the output of `round()` with the actual number?

Comment: OT: `if (p == NULL)` will never be true. You seem to be misunderstanding [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) and its second argument. And for this use-case you don't really need that argument.

Comment: @EvanHendler i need to use recursion

Comment: You aren't returning when `n == 0`, so you recursively call on `n - 4`, triggering the non-divisibility `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the function should not output any message. It is the caller of the function that will issue a message.

So the function return type should not be `void`.

With your approach the function will not work correctly with signed integers. So there is no sense to declare the function parameter as having the signed integer type `int`. And the function should have only one parameter.

The function can be defined the following way as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int power4( unsigned int n )
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (n < 4)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        unsigned int i = power4( n - 4 );
        return i == -1 ? -1 : 1 + i;
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    for ( unsigned int n = 0; n < 13; n++ )
    {
        unsigned int i = power4( n );

        if (i != -1)
        {
            printf( "4*%d = %d\n", i, n );
        }
        else
        {
            puts( "!p4" );
        }
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
4*0 = 0
!p4
!p4
!p4
4*1 = 4
!p4
!p4
!p4
4*2 = 8
!p4
!p4
!p4
4*3 = 12
```

To convert command line argument you can use standard function `strtoul` as for example

```
unsigned int n = ( unsigned int )strtoul( argv[1], NULL, 10 );
```

If you want to check whether the conversion was successful then you need to supply the second parameter of the call of `strtoul` unequal to NULL and check its value after the call and the value of errno.

Answer (score 0):

You needed to catch the case when `n==0` and then return. You were progressing a level too deep with input `-4`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int power4(int n, int i) {
  if (n == 0)
    return 1;
  if (n < 0 || n == 1)
    return -1;
  return power4(n - 4, i + 1);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int c;
  if (argc != 2)
    return 1;
  c = strtol(&argv[1][2],NULL, 10);
  if (errno == EINVAL || errno == ERANGE)
    return 1;
  if(c != 0)
    c = power4(c, 1);
  printf("%sMultiple of Four\n",c > 0?"":"Not a ");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've done the same thing in my updated version but it doesn't work

Comment: 12 is a multiple of 4 in this.

Comment: Only issue with it is that it says 0 is a multiple of 4, but that's an easy fix...

Comment: I've tried your solution but it gave me the same error, "program exited with code 1" even if I choose n = 12 or n = 8.

Comment: Oh, do you have to say "n=8" at the command line?

Comment: So, this one will only work if you say "n=8". It'll fail with "n = 8". You could use `strchr` until the last occurrance of `=` and ` `.